# merge multiple string values into one df column

Tags: python, pandas

apologies my multiple attempts looking through SO have been in vain. I need some assistance with the below:

I have a df as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject' : ['Eng' ,'Math', 'Science'], 'role' : ['Teacher', '', 'Dr'], 'ID' : ['123', '444', 'NaN'] })
 print(df)

    ID  role    subject
0   123 Teacher Eng
1   444         Math
2   NaN Dr      Science
```

As this is potentially unvalidated data, what I would usually do (in excel boo) is to create a memo field which aggregates the data and does not potentially damage any good data on upload.

so I've been toying with itterrows to try to loop through the df and merge the fields into one. The caveat being that I need to use /n to separate the values in the same column (CHAR(10) for you excel buffs)

so I've tried..

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
if row['ID'] and row['subject] and row['role'] == "": #search row for any data while leaving out blanks
    row['C_MEMO'] = row[['ID', 'subject', 'role']]
else:
    pass
```

but this isn't really working, any advice/help would be appreciated.

my desired output:

```
   ID        role      subject C_MEMO
0   123     Teacher     Eng     123,
                                Teacher
                                Eng

1   444                 Math    444,
                                Math

2   NaN     Dr          Science Dr,
                                Science
```

things to consider:

I'm working with multiple data types.

I'm happy to have the new output as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#first replace values
df = df.replace(['', 'NaN'], np.nan)
df["C_MEMO"] = df.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Or if missing values are strings only:

```
df["C_MEMO"] = df.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x[~x.isin(['', 'NaN'])]), axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df)
   subject     role   ID             C_MEMO
0      Eng  Teacher  123  Eng\nTeacher\n123
1     Math      NaN  444          Math\n444
2  Science       Dr  NaN        Science\nDr
```

Comment: @Datanovice - some problem ?

Comment: yep I got : TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, Timestamp found', 'occurred at index 0') would I also need to subset my columns into a new df to apply this?

Comment: @Datanovice - give me a sec.

Comment: @Datanovice - Then use `df["C_MEMO"] = df.apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)`

Comment: PERFECT! you are the man! i'll go over this to understand what you've done.

Comment: @Datanovice - It was converted possible non string values to `string`s after removing missing values.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject' : ['Eng' ,'Math', 'Science'], 'role' : ['Teacher', '', 'Dr'], 'ID' : ['123', '444', 'NaN'] })
df["C_MEMO"] = (df["ID"] + "," + df["role"] + "," +  df["subject"]).str.replace(",,", ",")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    ID     role  subject           C_MEMO
0  123  Teacher      Eng  123,Teacher,Eng
1  444              Math         444,Math
2  NaN       Dr  Science   NaN,Dr,Science
```

Or using `df.apply`

```
df["C_MEMO"] = df.apply(lambda x: ", ".join([x["ID"], x["role"], x["subject"]]).replace(", ,", ","), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks buddy! this is really helpful to subset the columns I need within the same df.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `str.join`:

```
bad_vals = {'', 'Nan'}
df['C_Memo'] = [', '.join([i for i in row if i not in bad_vals]) for row in df.values]

print(df)

    ID     role  subject             C_Memo
0  123  Teacher      Eng  123, Teacher, Eng
1  444              Math          444, Math
2  NaN       Dr  Science        Dr, Science
```

This is not necessarily worse than `pd.DataFrame.apply`, which has overheads associated with iterating over `pd.Series` objects for each row.

Comment: Thank you sir, I went with jezrael's solution but this is very readable so i'll defo take a copy of it! :)